# Symfony2 proper use for services

Tags: class, symfony, architecture, model

we are currently in the process of choosing a new framework for our application which is using a heavily customised version of Joomla at the moment. After trying to integrate a few different frameworks into the current system we decided symfony best fits our requirements. The old app uses MVC with the bulk of tasks being done in the model class. We are wanting to keep the model layer so we are setting up a bundle for model/data which will potentially double up as an API. The app will be a separate bundle calling on models from the model bundle.

That's some background on how we are modelling the app. Now we are trying to decide how we should call the models. At the moment we are using services.yml in the app bundle to include the model classes. I have been reading that services should be used for what I would call helper classes which can be used throughout the application. I'm just wondering if anyone with more experience with symfony could shed some light on the decisions we have made and is using services.yml to include our model classes is a good idea or could it be something we may regret in the future. We will be rewriting the app as we slowly port it across and are running old and new side by side.

Comment: Why do you want to use `services.yml` to call your models classes? Can't you just create entities in each bundle?

Comment: The reason why I am asking this question. Entities are something I will look into now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you globaly misconcieved what was used for what purpose. Your model is to be stored in your Entity folder, relations beween your entities are handled by [Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html), but entities are nothing more than Plain Old PHP Objects.

They are then used by the Controller(s). Your logic can then be devided in services, for many good reasons (better testability, readability, maintainability ...). It is those services that use `services.yml`. Therefor your model has nothing to do with your `services.yml` file, and they should be kept separate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ye this makes sense. We may or may not use doctrine. The data is stored in various ways. It just seemed like a quick way to have model classes available from a bundle only having to update one file services.yml.

Comment: It's not any longer to create a new Entity, it can be done in a single console line : 


`php app/console doctrine:generate:entity`


And I strongly recommend the use of Doctrine, it's by far the most convenient ORM you can have on a Symfony project.